# How to Drop Multiple Columns By Conditional Index Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you drop multiple columns by a conditional index value? For example, I'd like to drop all columns that are greater than index number 40.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(120).reshape(60, 2),
                  columns=['A', 'B'])
```

You can drop the columns when the index is greater than a specified value (for instance 40):

```
value=40
rows_to_drop=df.index[np.where(df.index>value)[0]]
df=df.drop(rows_to_drop,axis=0)
```

`df` now has the columns that have an index less than 40.

I hope I have understood your question.